# Using the Born rule to measure UV divergence?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, quantum-measurements

> **A typical use of cutoffs is to prevent singularities from appearing
>   during calculation.** If some quantities are computed as integrals over
>   energy or another physical quantity, these cutoffs determine the
>   limits of integration. The exact physics is reproduced when the
>   appropriate cutoffs are sent to zero or infinity. However, these
>   integrals are often divergent – see IR divergence and UV divergence –
>   and a cutoff is needed. **The dependence of physical quantities on the
>   chosen cutoffs** (especially the ultraviolet cutoffs) is the main focus
>   of the theory of the renormalisation group.
>   - [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutoff_(physics))

My naive question is during the measurement the Born rule dictates there should be a a non-zero probability of "accidentally" reaching a state where the cut-off is necessary.

Obviously this has not happened yet. I am certain there must be some error in my reasoning. But I am unsure what?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you are asking. I suspect that's why you haven't gotten an answer yet. You might want to go into more detail on why you think a cutoff in quantum field theory has to do with states and the Born rule, and why this is a problem

Comment: @octonion I was under the impression the "physical quantities on the chosen cutoffs" would be problematic - especially regarding a corresponding eigenstate. For example, I 'm not sure why this wouldn't affect say a stress energy tensor which has been cut-off.

Comment: certainly the cutoff would affect operators like the stress energy tensor if you look at it on momentum scales at around the order of the cutoff. It's still not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: The idea is the physical quantities you calibrate to in renormalization are always at a scale far removed from the cutoff, is that what bothers you?

Comment: @octonion won't I be able to reach such a scale by the Born rule? (say I measure energy) I might be making a subtle mis-assumption.

Comment: Maybe this will help. A kind of physical quantity we match to is for instance the mass of a particle. As long as the mass of the particle is much less than the cutoff we haven't done anything inconsistent. Now even if you think of your particles as wave packets with varying momentum and energy, the mass is not in a superposition (if it were, we would call the other mass value a different particle!)

Answer (score 1):

I think what bothers you is you aren't quite clear what are the kind of physical quantities we match to in renormalization. I suspect you haven't looked so much at quantum field theory itself so I will explain using quantum mechanics.

Consider an anharmonic oscillator in ordinary quantum mechanics (a potential with higher polynomial terms than just $x^2$). We might want to study this in perturbation theory, and in doing so we will get integrals analogous to the kind of integrals we get in quantum field theory. In this case the integrals are all finite, but nothing is stopping us from evaluating them using a cutoff. In fact if we wanted to evaluate them numerically, we would use some kind of discrete lattice (e.g. Simpson's rule).

If we used these integrals with a cutoff to calculate the energy eigenvalues of the anharmonic oscillator, we certainly would not trust any eigenvalues corresponding to frequencies oscillating at the same order as our lattice spacing (and also we would not expect perturbation theory to work very well for these high eigenvalues, but that's a separate issue). But we would expect that the low eigenvalues were calculated well.

The kind of physical quantities we match to in renormalization are like these low eigenvalues. In particular the mass of a particle in QFT is very much like the difference between the first excited eigenvalue and the ground state in ordinary quantum mechanics.

These low energy eigenvalues are a property of the theory as a whole, and not measured from a particular state per se. True any given evolving wave packet in the harmonic oscillator would have a superposition of energies, and you could pick a state that includes energies that are near our cutoff, where we don't trust our calculation. But the high energies are completely irrelevant to the renormalization process which only cares about the value of the low eigenvalues.

Comment: Can you update your answer in light of this? I'm rolling for interpretation 2 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/51990/do-quantum-fields-exist-in-superposition . In light of that I don't see why the eigenket I can possibly reach be problematic? Why? Because by spectral theorem I should be able to reconstruct the Hamiltonian? For example of a version of QFT which uses this explicitly: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Wightman_quantum_field_theory

Comment: @MoreAnonymous, Please read my answer first. I address the kind of physical quantities we match to in renormalization, and why a superposition of energies or field eigenstates or what have you is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm trying to get it. So I can effectively measure the all the eigenenergies in QM  reconstruct the Hamiltonain via spectral theorem for example: $H = \sum E_n|E_n \rangle \langle E_n |$. Now by the Born rule there is nothing stopping me from going beyond the UV cut-off and reconstructing the Hamiltonian. Also, I'm considering UV divergences - so these are the "high eigenvalues"

Comment: @MoreAnonymous, We aren't measuring energies and reconstructing our Hamiltonian like that at all. We *calculate* the eigenvalues in terms of integrals that have some cutoff $\Lambda$. All our eigenvalues are in terms of formulas that have $\Lambda$ in them, which was arbitrarily set and not physical. But we can pick a particular formula for a low eigenvalue $\lambda$, and invert it to get $\Lambda$ as a function of $\lambda$. Then all our formulas depend on the physical parameter $\lambda$ not $\Lambda$. Then to fit our theory to the physical world we just measure this one parameter $\lambda$.

Comment: So $H(\Lambda) = \sum E_n(\Lambda)|E_n \rangle \langle E_n |$? Also if you introduce cut-offs why is $\sum |E_n (\Lambda) \rangle \langle E_n (\Lambda) | = 1$ ?

Comment: @MoreAnonymous, If you want to introduce a cutoff and have the theory still be perfectly unitary (the condition you are asking about), you need to take the cutoff seriously from the very beginning. It is difficult to explain using my ordinary QM mechanics example, but let's consider the cutoff as being a finite lattice spacing that the fields are defined on. It simply doesn't make any sense to talk about the field eigenstates varying on scales shorter than the lattice spacing (since they only take values on the lattice, not any values in between) so you never run into problems with unitarity.